Не получается включить микрофон на ноуте Honor под Debian12
Купил ноут Honor (MagicBook X16 Plus 2024, если инфа поможет) на замену старичку. Все определилось и работает, кроме микрофона. Вывод звука норм работает - и на динамики и на наушники при их подключении к ноуту, а микрофон ни в какую не хочет. Пробовал разные варианты, найденные в инете - победить не удалось. Может кто-то сталкивался и решал подобную проблему?
Буду благодарен за любую помощь - очень неудобно присоединяться к рабочим созвонам дополнительно с телефона, чтобы можно было общаться.
lspci | grep Audio
c2:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Rembrandt Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
c2:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor (rev 63)
c2:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller

inxi -A
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Rembrandt Radeon High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: AMD ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor driver: N/A
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h/19h HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  API: ALSA v: k6.1.0-27-amd64 status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PulseAudio v: 16.1 status: active

amixer
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 65536
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch cswitch-joined
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 65536
  Front Left: Capture 65536 [100%] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 65536 [100%] [on]


На старых было что микрофон не выключат mute. Поставь alsamixer, переключись в нем с пульса на хв, дерни рычажок на микрофоне и сними мьют с него и с канала рядом.

Пробовал - со всех столбиков снят MM
